# React Native Release apk failing on accessing camera view

Tags: reactjs, react-native, android-camera, live, mux

Am trying to do live stream with nodemediaclient library and everything works fine on debug apk. But on release apk, node media client is unable to fetch camera feed.

App crashed right after collecting permission for camera & audio. This is my code of the live page

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


import { NodeCameraView } from "react-native-nodemediaclient";

    async componentDidMount() {
        const cameraPermission = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
            PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.CAMERA
          )

          const microphonePermission = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
            PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.RECORD_AUDIO
          )

          if (cameraPermission === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED){
             ToastAndroid.show('Camera permission activated', 5)
            this.setState({
                cameraPermission: 'authorized'
            });

          }

          if (microphonePermission === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED){
             ToastAndroid.show('Microphone permission ', 5)
            this.setState({
                microphonePermission: 'authorized'
            });
          }
    render() {

        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>

                {
          cameraPermission == 'authorized' && microphonePermission == 'authorized' &&

            <NodeCameraView
              style={styles.videoStream}
              ref={vb => {
                this.vb = vb;
              }}
              outputUrl={
                `rtmp://api-mux/app/${params.key}`
              }
              camera={{cameraId: 1, cameraFrontMirror: true}}
              audio={{bitrate: 32000, profile: 1, samplerate: 44100}}
              video={{
                preset: 4,
                bitrate: 400000,
                profile: 1,
                fps: 15,
                videoFrontMirror: false,
              }}
              autopreview={true}
              smoothSkinLevel = {1}
            />

          </View>
        }

                </View>
        );
    }  
}
```

Comment: I haven't used node media client, but both RN camera packages I used insisted on managing permissions. I solved a similar issue by ensuring permissions were granted before ever showing the camera component.

Comment: Interesting and can you let me know how your androidmanifest.xml looked like? What are all the <uses-feature> you called for camera access?

Comment: It looks like just camera: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />` is the only one I see that it needed.  This was for react-native-camera though.

Comment: Got it. Am kinda new to react native. Would be extremely helpful if you could share github link if any or code on how to use RN camera packages to fetch camera feed and pass it to server as a live stream?

Comment: Sorry, can't share my work code.  I think the implementation is going to be somewhat tied to the streaming service you choose.  Something like this may be helpful https://www.syntx.io/react-native/video-live-streaming-with-react-native/

Comment: Thanks, let me check the link you shared and get back. I appreciate your time.

Comment: @abe So, I ran sentry react native to find the error on crashing. It shows as "segfault". Do you think of any solution for this?

Comment: I'm not sure.  I would google for similar errors.  And, if it's feasible, try a different camera package.  Sorry I don't have more specific advice.